# How to write SQL query to sum deposits and withdrawals per user

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like below with list of deposits and withdraws.i need to write a query to obtain what all are the deposits and withdrawals per user

Sample Input table

[image]

and the output should be

[image]

The sql code so for i have tried is

```
select name, 
       sum (case when  money >= 0 then money else 0 end) as sum_of_deposits,
       sum (case when money < 0 then  money else 0 end) as sum_of_withdrawals 
from transfers GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and clarify where you're having difficulty. Have you looked at `SUM`, `CASE`, and `GROUP BY`??

Comment: Hi @fubar i tried the below query.it returns the whole deposits and withdrawals.not sure how to take it for individual user 
select sum (case when  money >= 0 then money else 0 end) as sum_of_deposits,
       sum (case when money < 0 then  money  else 0 end) as sum_of_withdrawals
from table

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so and run into difficulties, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help.

Comment: The query in your question doesn't work?

Comment: Please do not post sample data as screenshots

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL 9.4 or + you can use the FILTER  clause for aggregate function, is a new features from this version, combine with group by clause for user grouping, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE so (u text, v int);

INSERT INTO so VALUES ('a',-10000), ('b',10000),('a',2000),('c',-100);

SELECT u, 
sum(v) FILTER (WHERE v>=0) dep,
sum(abs(v)) FILTER (WHERE v<0)withdraws
FROM so
GROUP BY 1;
```

try to adjust this example for your case, the abs function return the absolute value of a number passed as an argument, this is for avoid negatives values

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is basically correct.  The only issue is the sign:

```
select name,
       sum(case when money > 0 then money else 0 end) as sum_of_deposits,
       sum(case when money < 0 then -money else 0 end) as sum_of_withdrawals
from transfers 
group by name;
```

I do agree that `filter` is a more direct way of answering the question:

```
select name,
       sum(v) filter (where v > 0) as sum_of_deposits,
       sum(- v) filter (where v < 0) as num_of_withdrawals
from transfers
group by name;
```

But `case` is also a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This example works with 'GROUP BY' feature.
Your answer was so close to the solution but you have to keep in mind that 'CASE' function elaborate with all the values(=money) that passed. Not separated.

```
SELECT name, 
    sum(deposits) as sum_of_deposits, 
    sum(withdrawals) as sum_of_withdrawals
FROM (
    SELECT name,
        CASE 
            WHEN (money>0) THEN sum(money)
            ELSE (0)
        END as deposits,
        CASE 
            WHEN (money<0) THEN sum(abs(money))
            ELSE (0)
        END as withdrawals
    FROM transfers
    GROUP BY money
)
GROUP BY name;
```

Results : [results.sqliteDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIR9f.png)

Answer (score 0):

**COALESCE** function can be used in order to replace null with 0

```
 select name,
 coalesce(sum(case when amount>0 then amount end), 0) as sum_deposits,
 coalesce(sum(case when amount<0 then amount end), 0) as sum_transfers
 from transfers
 group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

--Try this, it will work

select name,
sum (case when  money >= 0 then money else 0 end) as sum_of_deposits,
sum (case when money < 0 then ABS(money) else 0 end) as sum_of_withdrawals
from transfers GROUP BY name
order by name

Comment: Even if this answer helped OP, please add a description as this help others in long run.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).